# VirtManager libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor

Tags: linux, qemu, archlinux, kvm, libvirt

I am using Archlinux with `virt-manager` and `kvm`. When I conifgured like this and I got these errors below. Can somebody help me solve it? Thank you a lot!

[Configration of Display Spice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nm5Hc.png)

[Configration of Video Virtio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZSBQ.png)

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1384, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 1352, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor
```

And I found these in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/$MYGUESTNAME.log`, but I cannot figure out what's wrong with it.

```
2022-06-24 03:05:53.851+0000: starting up libvirt version: 8.4.0, qemu version: 7.0.0, kernel: 5.18.6-arch1-1, hostname: ArchPorn.localdomain
LC_ALL=C \
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin \
HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-archlinux \
XDG_DATA_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-archlinux/.local/share \
XDG_CACHE_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-archlinux/.cache \
XDG_CONFIG_HOME=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-archlinux/.config \
/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 \
-name guest=archlinux,debug-threads=on \
-S \
-object '{"qom-type":"secret","id":"masterKey0","format":"raw","file":"/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/domain-1-archlinux/master-key.aes"}' \
-machine pc-q35-7.0,usb=off,vmport=off,dump-guest-core=off,memory-backend=pc.ram \
-accel kvm \
-cpu host,migratable=on \
-m 6144 \
-object '{"qom-type":"memory-backend-ram","id":"pc.ram","size":6442450944}' \
-overcommit mem-lock=off \
-smp 4,sockets=4,cores=1,threads=1 \
-uuid 668eec0e-75a5-46cd-8379-4d493e59ae8a \
-no-user-config \
-nodefaults \
-chardev socket,id=charmonitor,fd=33,server=on,wait=off \
-mon chardev=charmonitor,id=monitor,mode=control \
-rtc base=utc,driftfix=slew \
-global kvm-pit.lost_tick_policy=delay \
-no-hpet \
-no-shutdown \
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 \
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s4=1 \
-boot strict=on \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":16,"chassis":1,"id":"pci.1","bus":"pcie.0","multifunction":true,"addr":"0x2"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":17,"chassis":2,"id":"pci.2","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x1"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":18,"chassis":3,"id":"pci.3","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x2"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":19,"chassis":4,"id":"pci.4","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x3"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":20,"chassis":5,"id":"pci.5","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x4"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":21,"chassis":6,"id":"pci.6","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x5"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":22,"chassis":7,"id":"pci.7","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x6"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":23,"chassis":8,"id":"pci.8","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x2.0x7"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":24,"chassis":9,"id":"pci.9","bus":"pcie.0","multifunction":true,"addr":"0x3"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":25,"chassis":10,"id":"pci.10","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x3.0x1"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":26,"chassis":11,"id":"pci.11","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x3.0x2"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":27,"chassis":12,"id":"pci.12","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x3.0x3"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":28,"chassis":13,"id":"pci.13","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x3.0x4"}' \
-device '{"driver":"pcie-root-port","port":29,"chassis":14,"id":"pci.14","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x3.0x5"}' \
-device '{"driver":"qemu-xhci","p2":15,"p3":15,"id":"usb","bus":"pci.2","addr":"0x0"}' \
-device '{"driver":"virtio-serial-pci","id":"virtio-serial0","bus":"pci.3","addr":"0x0"}' \
-blockdev '{"driver":"file","filename":"/home/fansuregrin/VMs/archlinux.qcow2","node-name":"libvirt-2-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}' \
-blockdev '{"node-name":"libvirt-2-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-2-storage","backing":null}' \
-device '{"driver":"virtio-blk-pci","bus":"pci.4","addr":"0x0","drive":"libvirt-2-format","id":"virtio-disk0","bootindex":1}' \
-device '{"driver":"ide-cd","bus":"ide.0","id":"sata0-0-0"}' \
-netdev tap,fd=34,vhost=on,vhostfd=36,id=hostnet0 \
-device '{"driver":"virtio-net-pci","netdev":"hostnet0","id":"net0","mac":"52:54:00:cf:92:94","bus":"pci.1","addr":"0x0"}' \
-chardev pty,id=charserial0 \
-device '{"driver":"isa-serial","chardev":"charserial0","id":"serial0","index":0}' \
-chardev socket,id=charchannel0,fd=32,server=on,wait=off \
-device '{"driver":"virtserialport","bus":"virtio-serial0.0","nr":1,"chardev":"charchannel0","id":"channel0","name":"org.qemu.guest_agent.0"}' \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charchannel1,name=vdagent \
-device '{"driver":"virtserialport","bus":"virtio-serial0.0","nr":2,"chardev":"charchannel1","id":"channel1","name":"com.redhat.spice.0"}' \
-device '{"driver":"usb-tablet","id":"input0","bus":"usb.0","port":"1"}' \
-audiodev '{"id":"audio1","driver":"spice"}' \
-spice port=0,disable-ticketing=on,image-compression=off,gl=on,rendernode=/dev/dri/by-path/pci-0000:00:02.0-render,seamless-migration=on \
-device '{"driver":"virtio-vga-gl","id":"video0","max_outputs":1,"bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1"}' \
-device '{"driver":"ich9-intel-hda","id":"sound0","bus":"pcie.0","addr":"0x1b"}' \
-device '{"driver":"hda-duplex","id":"sound0-codec0","bus":"sound0.0","cad":0,"audiodev":"audio1"}' \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir0,name=usbredir \
-device '{"driver":"usb-redir","chardev":"charredir0","id":"redir0","bus":"usb.0","port":"2"}' \
-chardev spicevmc,id=charredir1,name=usbredir \
-device '{"driver":"usb-redir","chardev":"charredir1","id":"redir1","bus":"usb.0","port":"3"}' \
-device '{"driver":"virtio-balloon-pci","id":"balloon0","bus":"pci.5","addr":"0x0"}' \
-object '{"qom-type":"rng-random","id":"objrng0","filename":"/dev/urandom"}' \
-device '{"driver":"virtio-rng-pci","rng":"objrng0","id":"rng0","bus":"pci.6","addr":"0x0"}' \
-sandbox on,obsolete=deny,elevateprivileges=deny,spawn=deny,resourcecontrol=deny \
-msg timestamp=on
2022-06-24 03:05:54.292+0000: shutting down, reason=failed
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a sign that QEMU has unexpectedly crashed. if you are lucky there will be more useful error information in `/var/log/libvirt/qemu/$GUESTNAME.log` that will help you diagnose the problem

Comment: Dear bro, I pasted some contents of my log file in the question area, but I still cannot solve it. So, if you can help me to figure it out, thank you a lot!

Comment: Maybe try to launch the qemu command that libvirt tried found in the logs manually, perhaps you will have more details.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the reason for failure was mentioned at the end of the stacktrace.

`Image is not in qcow2 format`

While libvirt was expecting a qcow2, I was providing it a vmdk, hence the error.

```py
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libvirt.py", line 4026, in createXML
    if ret is None:raise libvirtError('virDomainCreateXML() failed', conn=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"node-name":"libvirt-1-format","read-only":false,"driver":"qcow2","file":"libvirt-1-storage","backing":null}: Image is not in qcow2 format
```